# What means the opts attribute in Test-Kitchen commands?

Tags: test-kitchen

I am using [Test-Kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/wiki/Getting-Started) for my integration test and I have a few doubts about the Kitchen command specificaly about the **opts** attribute

It is the kitchen commands.

```bash
Commands:
  kitchen console                          # Kitchen Console!
  kitchen converge [(all|<REGEX>)] [opts]  # Converge one or more instances
  kitchen create [(all|<REGEX>)] [opts]    # Create one or more instances
  kitchen destroy [(all|<REGEX>)] [opts]   # Destroy one or more instances
  kitchen diagnose [(all|<REGEX>)]         # Show computed diagnostic configuration
  kitchen driver                           # Driver subcommands
  kitchen driver create [NAME]             # Create a new Kitchen Driver gem project
  kitchen driver discover                  # Discover Test Kitchen drivers published on RubyGems
  kitchen driver help [COMMAND]            # Describe subcommands or one specific subcommand
  kitchen help [COMMAND]                   # Describe available commands or one specific command
  kitchen init                             # Adds some configuration to your cookbook so Kitchen can rock
  kitchen list [(all|<REGEX>)]             # List all instances
  kitchen login (['REGEX']|[INSTANCE])     # Log in to one instance
  kitchen setup [(all|<REGEX>)] [opts]     # Setup one or more instances
  kitchen test [all|<REGEX>)] [opts]       # Test one or more instances
  kitchen verify [(all|<REGEX>)] [opts]    # Verify one or more instances
  kitchen version
```

Has anyone used for example `kitchen converge [opts]`.

What kind of **options** can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `kitchen help converge` - it will show you all the options. You can run `kitchen help <command>` for any command to get more information. The list of options varies by command.

For example:

```
kitchen converge --concurrency 5 --parallel
```

Comment: I am using kitchen 1.0.0, and when I execute kitchen help converge, it just shows me the option --parallel ( -p ). @sethvargo Could you tell me where did you find the option --concurrency 5? I am looking information about that.

Comment: Update to the latest version